# Getting Value from disabled attribute in html

Tags: javascript, html

I had a form which can edit some parameters and some are disabled.While uploading the edited form the disabled parameters returned null value,my code is as follows,

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label class="control-label required"  for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" readonly="readonly" disabled value="{user.name}}">
</div>
```

So while submitting the form ,should uses value "user.name" but it returns null since I provide disabled attribute.

Comment: If you mark it as `disabled` then it won't pass along its value. Perhaps you can mark it as `readonly` if that fits your requirement?

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj Using readonly make the parameter similar to other where editing cursor is there but cant'edit.but my requirement is it should be look like `disabled` but it should pass its value

Comment: how about using js to enable them just before sending ? you should be able to do it overiding `form.onsubmit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use only `readonly` instead of `disabled`

There is 2 choices :

```
<input type="text" value="{{user.name}}" readonly>
// In this case you can get post values  

<input type="text" value="{{user.name}}" disabled>
// In this case you can not get post values
```

Answer (score 4):

> my requirement is it should be look like disabled but it should pass its value

You can use CSS to make it look disabled

```css
.disabled {
  background: #ccc;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="disabled" />
<input type="password" readonly="readonly" class="disabled" />
<textarea readonly="readonly" class="disabled"></textarea>
```